# Factorisation of an element into irreducibles - Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I wanted to know if this fact was correct: Suppose we have a ring $R$, and an element $r \in R$. Suppose $r$ has two different factorisations into irreducibles. Then $R$ cannot be a Principal ideal domain Is this  true and if so could anyone tell me why  this is so?

Comment: True, since every PID is a UFD, which is a standard fact. If you get tired of waiting for someone to write an answer here (or possibly finding a duplicate question), just google "proof pid ufd".

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=ab=xy$ be two different factorisations in irreducibles. Suppose $R$ is a PID. Then $\exists c$ such that $r\in (a) \cap (x) =(c)$. Thus there exist $c',c'',z$ with $c=ac'=xc''$ and $r=cz=ac'z=xc''z$. Now, a PID is a domain, therefore $b=c'z$ and $y=c''z$. Since $b$ and $y$ are irreducible, either $z$ is a unit and then $r=c$ which implies that $r$ divides $a$ and $x$, impossible. Or $c'$ and $c''$ are units which implies that $a=xc''(c')^{-1}$, i.e., the decompositions were not different to start with.

Thus $R$ is not a PID.